# React-Tabulator component crashing when more than 1 instance

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tabulator, react-functional-component

I have a component which renders a react-tabulator component inside it.

If I try to render 2 instances of this component, then Tabulator throws the error when inside Storybook and the same error but for 'setColumns' instead of 'destroy' when the wrapper component is instantiated multiple times with the target application.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of null
    at default_1.push../node_modules/react-tabulator/lib/ReactTabulator.js.default_1.componentWillUnmount (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:231022:20)
    at callComponentWillUnmountWithTimer (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:214466:12)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:195074:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:195123:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:195178:31)
    at safelyCallComponentWillUnmount (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:214473:5)
    at commitUnmount (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:214995:11)
    at commitNestedUnmounts (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:215049:5)
    at unmountHostComponents (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:215329:7)
    at commitDeletion (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.72ccccb1e4a331ed682e.bundle.js:215386:5)
```

I've tried this in different environments for example within Storybook:

```
export const BasicTable = () => (
    <>
        <Table isEditable={true} data={data} schema={schemaSmall} />
        <Table isEditable={true} data={data} schema={schemaSmall} />
    </>
);
```

There is no problem with the schema or data as both will render correctly if there is only 1 instance.

The wrapper component is a React functional component that is utilising the useRef hook to reference the React-Tabulator instance, is it possible that the 2 hook refs are clashing?

This is from a rather large component but the (IMO) pertinent parts from Table.jsx are:

```
import 'react-tabulator/lib/styles.css';
import 'react-tabulator/lib/css/tabulator.min.css';
import { reactFormatter, ReactTabulator } from 'react-tabulator';

const Table = ({
    data,
    schema,
}) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const [tableColumns, setTableColumns] = useState([]);

    // is only running once per instance
    useEffect(() => {
        // builds an array of columns
        setTableColumns(array);
    }, [amEditing]

    const options = {
       history: true,
       layoutColumnsOnNewData: true,
       virtualDom: false,
   };
   return (
      <StyledWrapper style={{ width }}>
        <ReactTabulator
            ref={ref}
            columns={tableColumns}
            data={[]}
            options={options}
        />
       </StyledWrapper>
   );
};
```

result: the Table.jsx component has no errors within either environments if used in the singular.

result: the Table.jsx component works fine alongside multiple instances of the original React-Tabulator component.

If it is the useRef hook then is there a way around this?
I can't see any other possible reason for this failing

**UPDATE 1:**
I tested out the useRef theory by duplicating the react-tabulator instantiation within the Table.jsx component and gave each a different ref:

```
const ref = useRef();
const ref1 = useRef();
```

but this still didn't work and threw the same error with one Table.jsx instance. (and wouldn't have solved the issue anyway as an unknown number of instantiations would be required).

**UPDATE 2:**
With help I've managed to narrow down the issue. When the Table.jsx is instantiated it is passed a schema and data, the schema is parsed inside to build an array of columns which is applied to a hook:

```
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([])
```

columns is then referenced within the declaration of ReactTabulator.

When running a single instance of Table.jsx then this works completely fine, but when running multiple instances it crashes.

result:

- if the dynamic array outputted to setColumns is copied and applied directly to ReactTabulator then there is no issue - there is no unmount
- if the dynamic array outputted to setColumns is copied and set as the initial value of the hook then the issue still occurs - unmount happens

This doesn't explain to me though my the error is 'null' because  always exists, and the column hook has a default empty array.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think that `ref` props has any effect. I looked into the source code of react-tabulator, it's just unused. So `useRef()` shouldn't do any harm.

I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. My theory is there's a "flash unmount" happening somewhere inside your app. By "flash umount" I mean a component get mounted then immediately unmounted for some reason.

To test my theory, try replace `<ReactTabulator />` with this dummy component:

```
function Dummy() {
  const id = useRef(Math.random()).current
  console.log(`rendering dummy_${id}`)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`mounted dummy_${id}`)
    return () => {
      console.log(`HEADS UP! Unmounted dummy_${id}`)
    }
  }, [])
  return <div>{id}</div>
}
```

Try render multiple instances of this `<Dummy />` component in place of `<ReactTabulator />`. If you observe the "unmounted" message logged out, then my theory is proven right.

---

**UPDATE**:
I forget to mention the reasoning to come up with above theory. The original error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of null` source from [this line](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/blob/69bbe9d3ac75c4e2eb47ccde9a9bc59dd85b4740/src/ReactTabulator.tsx#L54):

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.table.destroy();
}
```

It happens because `react-tabulator` lib internally uses an `async componentDidMount()` lifecycle, inside which it `await` for an async render event from React **before** it eventually instantiate `Tabulator` and assign to `this.table`.

Normally that async event should've resolved immediately, so `this.table` should've been assigned a value before `componentWillUnmount()`. However in your case, the "flash unmount" happens before that async event could resolve, thus `this.table` is `null` when `componentWillUnmount()` get called, thus the error.

For detail trace [this line](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/blob/69bbe9d3ac75c4e2eb47ccde9a9bc59dd85b4740/src/ReactTabulator.tsx#L30) in source code.

Comment: thanks for that. SO. I swapped  ReactTablulator for Dummy within Table component - all ran fine for multiple instances (no unmounts)

I then returned ReactTabulator with Dummy alongside with empty data and no props except columns - ran multiple instances and no issues or unmount.

I then ran the same setup with data and got the cannot read XXX of null error and both Dummy instances traced unmounted

Comment: FYI I've added a few more bits to the ticket - you're definitely correct that there is an unmount happening when we have multiple instances, but not when just one instance.

Comment: @Rich  I still don't see the actual problem in your posted code. I believe it's somewhere even upper in your component hierarchy. But I have no further idea.

Comment: Your explanation seems to give a reason why in certain cases I got a value of null for my reference to React-Tabulator in componentDidMount, e.g when such a code as this.tableref.current.table.setColumns(coldef) was executed. But strangely, this also affected to my simple dummy ref which simply referenced to html label, i.e it contained null. Without the aforementioned code, both my reference to React-Tabulator and dummy ref contained the expected value in componentDidMount.

Comment: However, this behaviour only happened recently when I had to re-install everything because my hard disc was damaged. Previously, my code ran as expected. So I am not really sure what actually caused this unexpected behaviour.

Comment: As a work around, in order to prevent error, I enclosed the required code in a condition such as : if (this.tableref.current.table) {this.tableref.current.table.setColumns(coldef)}